Expo Pop Up Stating "Error Uploading ImageProperty 'uri' Doesn't Exist (Firebase)
I'm a beginner in coding and have been attempting to create an Image Picker that uses Firebase as storage. At this point I am able to access my pictures and select them, however when I attempt to upload it to firebase via pressing the "add" button on my phone (I'm using an android if that matters), I'm receiving a pop up that states "Error Uploading ImageProperty 'uri' doesn't exist"
These are screenshots
(https://i.sstatic.net/J8kOZ.jpg) (https://i.sstatic.net/cwPLk.png)
(https://i.sstatic.net/Zw0pv.png) (https://i.sstatic.net/gPRLW.png)
``(https://i.sstatic.net/2ls1J.png)
I've tried using Google to find the answer, however the only examples that I see show this error message happening as the app itself is attempting to run on Expo Go; not after the app is running.
